# Generict django content type , get the object stored in contentype

Tags: python, django

Well similar questions have been asked, but none of the answers works for me .

Below is my contentype model

```py
class notifyall(models.Model):     
    target_instance=models.ForeignKey(ContentType,null=True,on_delete=models.CASCADE,blank=True)
    object_id=models.PositiveIntegerField(null=True)
    target_object=GenericForeignKey('target_instance', 'object_id')
```

As you can see, contentype has a GenericForeignKey to store different kind of objects from different models

when notifyall object is created , this is what i will get

```
>>object_id= e.g 20
>>target_instance = class_name_of_model
```

what is the right way to go about retrieving  the object stored in notifyall model as object_id  and target_instance

please give me your answers or suggestion in code base

Comment: You don't need to set the object_id and content_type, you can just set the target_object descriptor and use the same target_object descriptor for retrieving the object

Comment: @lain Shelvington ,please help me out with code related answer. So as i can understand what you talking about

Comment: it prints out none , when i use notifyall_instance.target_object

Comment: And when you print notifyall_instance.target_instance and notifyall_instance.object_id?

Comment: it prints the object number and prints model class